# Trying to create a sample table with sqlalchemy-spanner gives error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-spanner

I am using:
SQLAlchemy==1.3.0
sqlalchemy-spanner==1.6.2
Trying the sample in https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy/tree/main "Create a table" gives me:
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 [ERROR] syntax error at or near "PRIMARY"; failed to parse the DDL statements.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String
PROJECT = "prj***"
INSTANCE = "***"
DATABASE = "**"
URL = f"spanner+spanner:///projects/{PROJECT}/instances/{INSTANCE}/databases/{DATABASE}"
engine = create_engine(URL)

metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

table = Table(
  "users",
  metadata,
  Column("user_id", String(16), primary_key=True),
  Column("user_name", String(16), nullable=False),
)
table.create()
```

I have tried several different Columns, using a Class and then Base.metadata.create_all(). It sometimes says "user" column does not exist too, so I think it is translating the DDL statement wrong.Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the URL you are using is for version 1.4
As per the [documentation provided](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy#database-url) the URLs for 1.3 and 1.4 are in the following format:

```html
# for SQLAlchemy 1.3:
spanner:///projects/project-id/instances/instance-id/databases/database-id

# for SQLAlchemy 1.4:
spanner+spanner:///projects/project-id/instances/instance-id/databases/database-id
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The thing is I tried with both versions changing the connection string both ways, but now, although it says that in the docs, I could not connect if I use "spanner", just with "spanner+spanner"., even with 1.3 SQLAlchemy...